# UIImage bigger than custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have an UITableView with an custom UITableViewCell. In the cell, for style purposes, I have an UIImage that is much bigger than my custom cell, and what happens is that the image isn't cropped and it employs the other cells. Is there a way or a property to aviod this behaviour?
Thank you.

I'm not native english, for that reason I post this picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4mUN.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of table view data source, do `cell.clipsToBounds = YES`

Comment: `cell.clipsToBounds = YES` works fine :D!! Thank's all of you.

Comment: Need 15 reputation, when I'll have it, I will.

Comment: This only works, if the cell is the element that displays the UIImage. If you are using a UIImageView inside the UITableViewCell, you have to set clipsToBounds=true on the UImageView itself, not the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In the interface Builder , Select your image and Mark "Clip SubViews" in the attributes inspector panel

Comment: I still have the same problem, take a look to the picture I upload please. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Your UIImageView is set to Aspect fit? Have you tried setting `cell.clipsToBounds = YES` ?

Comment: Well, if he wants cell to clip subviews (which is image view), make UIImageView instance clip subviews wouldn't help.

Comment: `cell.clipsToBounds = YES` works fine :D!! Thank's all of you.